# Angular test : Missing locale data for the locale “XXX” with jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, internationalization

I'm working on an application using Angular 10 and Jest to test my app. I'put the Locale ID fr-FR and it works well but not in the tests when I run them :

`Error: Missing locale data for the locale "fr-FR".`

I don't know where or how to set the locale in the tests once for all. I've put in my tests that failed :  :

```
import {LOCALE_ID} from '@angular/core';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import {registerLocaleData} from '@angular/common';

registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr-Fr');

beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: LOCALE_ID,
            useValue: 'fr-FR'
        }
    ]
})})
```

I'm using locale date in a date formatter :

```
export default class DateFormatter {
  private static readonly YYYY_MM_DD = 'yyyy-MM-dd';

  public static readonly LOCALE_DATE: string = 'fr-FR';

  static formatDateDayWithDashes(date: Date) {
    return !!date ? formatDate(date, this.YYYY_MM_DD, this.LOCALE_DATE) : undefined;
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea where I can set the locale once for all the tests ?

Answer (score 4):

You can put global configuration in your setup-jest file.

If you don't have setup file, you can add it in your jest.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts',
  ],
  ...
};
```

In your setup-jest.ts :

```
[...maybe some preset...]
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr-FR');

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      {
        provide: LOCALE_ID,
        useValue: 'fr-FR',
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

Hope it'll help !